# print ONLY variables stored in the data segment of program using gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb

How can I print just values that are in the data segement of a program using gdb? I know that info variables shows all local and global variables. I also know i can just look at the assembly file of the program but is there a way to do this with gdb?

Comment: Not an expert on gdb.  `info proc mappings` will give you interesting addresses, and `info variables`  will show all variables with an address.  In my test case the ones of interest to you were listed first.